# Getting labels for legend after graphing pivot of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to have my plot show a legend where the column each value came from would have a label. I did not separate the plt.plot() from the pivot step but want to know if it is still possible to have a legend. One does not show up at all and if I add

```
plt.plot(df_EPErrorPercentByWeekAndDC.pivot(index='hellofresh delivery week', columns='DC', values='Error Percent'), label='DC')
```

it just uses that string as every label, if I add `df_EPErrorPercentByWeekAndDC['DC']` then it just shows one letter of it per legend item. Here is the code I have:

```
print("### Graphing Error Rates by Week and DC EP ###")
# remove percent sign from percent in place
df_EPErrorPercentByWeekAndDC['Error Percent'] = df_EPErrorPercentByWeekAndDC['Error Percent'].str[:-1].astype(float)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.plot(df_EPErrorPercentByWeekAndDC.pivot(index='hellofresh delivery week', columns='DC', values='Error Percent'))
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('EPErrorPercentByWeekAndDC.png', bbox_inches="tight", dpi=500)
plt.close()
```

and I cant share any of the data but it is in the format of a pivot table with columns with state names and each column is full of percentages, the graph works fine but the legend isnt there.

Comment: Ok I split it out and saved off the pivoted_frame, then put plt.legend(pivoted_frame.columns) but the chart still shows up without them when I do
plt.plot(pivoted_frame)
plt.savefig('HFErrorPercentByWeekAndDC.png', bbox_inches="tight", dpi=500)

oh wow nevermind I was putting the plt.plot after the plt.legend, apparently that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either save the pivoted frame then specify the legend as the columns:

```
df['Error Percent'] = df['Error Percent'].str[:-1].astype(float)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
pivoted_df = df.pivot(index='hellofresh delivery week', columns='DC',
                      values='Error Percent')
plt.plot(pivoted_df)
plt.legend(pivoted_df.columns, title=pivoted_df.columns.name)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1]

Or use [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) directly on the pivoted DataFrame which will handle the legend automatically:

```
df['Error Percent'] = df['Error Percent'].str[:-1].astype(float)
pivoted_df = df.pivot(index='hellofresh delivery week', columns='DC',
                      values='Error Percent')
ax = pivoted_df.plot(rot=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2]

---

Sample DataFrame and imports used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'hellofresh delivery week': np.repeat(
        pd.date_range('2021-05-01', periods=5, freq='W'), 2),
    'DC': ['A', 'B'] * 5,
    'Error Percent': pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, 100, 10), dtype=str) + '%'
})
```

`df`:

```
  hellofresh delivery week DC Error Percent
0               2021-05-02  A           88%
1               2021-05-02  B           71%
2               2021-05-09  A           26%
3               2021-05-09  B           83%
4               2021-05-16  A           18%
5               2021-05-16  B           72%
6               2021-05-23  A           37%
7               2021-05-23  B           40%
8               2021-05-30  A           90%
9               2021-05-30  B           17%
```

`pivoted_df`:

```
DC                           A     B
hellofresh delivery week            
2021-05-02                88.0  71.0
2021-05-09                26.0  83.0
2021-05-16                18.0  72.0
2021-05-23                37.0  40.0
2021-05-30                90.0  17.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for a second there I put the plt.plot after the plt.legend, apparently that doesn't work. But now it is working great and I appreciate it.